# PHP : Is there a way to load only CSS classes I need?

Tags: php, css, performance

I'm using PHP and each page of my website can return its own HTML elements in an array as the one below (right before being rendered). So I can get the complete list of HTML tags, classes and attributes that my page contains right before loading my CSS.

In a perfect world, I'm free to use "Bootstrap like" classes as "mx-lg-8", but "mx-lg-7" is not loaded if I don't need it.

I'm a dreaming ? :)
What would you do to optimize your CSS request ?

Thanks for your advice !

```
$HTML_elements = array(
    array( 
        'tag' => 'body',
        'atts' => array(
            'class' => array( 'mx-lg-8', 'bg-dark', 'text-red' ),
            'data-attribute' => 'attribute-value'
        ),
    ),
    array( 
        'tag' => 'header',
        'atts' => array(
            'class' => array( 'class-1', 'class-2', 'class-3' ),
        ),
    ),
    array( 
        'tag' => 'div',
        'atts' => array(
            'class' => array( 'class-1', 'class-2', 'class-3' ),
        ),
    ),
    #...
);
```

Comment: Unless you have a ludicrous amount of CSS then just minify and it and serve it, that's what everyone else does a and it doesn't cause problems. You'll spend a great deal of effort potentially trying to output only the exact classes you need and it will cause more server side processing, more code testing and maintenance, and almost no visible benefit to performance etc. If it was me, I would spend my time instead on something which actually adds value to the application.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that design means that every page request will need to generate and download its own CSS (as opposed to, e.g., using shared external and possibly cached CSS files). You'll be using more CPU and bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson for your wise reply. I guess I'll do something like that :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to save a few bytes on CSS?

- Minify the code https://cssminifier.com/
- Use compression, like GZ (and many others), which are transparent to the user and very well supported in the browsers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression and it can be used on your HTML/JS as well https://imagekit.io/blog/what-and-why-brotli-compression/ depends on the compression type, but for example gz is supported in browsers for ~2 decades (just google what year they introduced your desired compression in browsers you want to support)

But you want to be efficient? Then be prepared to waste some bytes.

- Remove a number of requests even if they will get bigger. TCP connection requires 3-way handshake which is a lot of work if you want to create a lot of extra requests, you will waste a lot of traffic and increase the server load just by adding the overhead. The trends are going exactly other way around, having bigger and less frequent loads so save on the network bandwidth and server loads (and being more efficient), it's called spritting https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ where you put multiple images into one so you reduce the amount of requests and in your CSS you are clever to select the specific "window" containing your sub-image. Or like a lot of things are using long connections (to avoid polling and doing the 3-way handshake) like websockets do.
- Cashing if you will use some of the features eventually, then there is no point to have selectively enabling them and disabling them and have a lot of different CSS, just keep one common one, which will be cashed and reused heavily (and that's effective)
- You need a smaller framework then use it, nobody is forcing you to use a big/heavy framework if you want to be super lightweight, nobody is stopping you from modifying the heavy one and trim away stuff you do not want. For light CSS I like https://purecss.io/
- A lot of frameworks support various subsections for download, base + forms/grids/columns/tabs/tables/buttons/menus, allowing you enable as little as needed without you having to do it yourself, if you do not like that granularity, then feel free DIY